What are the capabilities/limits of BLE advertising/broadcast?
I work in a pharma company where I have to build a system to control different cages that are filled with insects. Due to the regulations I was given, I have to create wireless devices with as less battery attached as possible.
I thought of the usage of BLE where I have one Master that tells the different slaves what to do (e.g. turning on/off a small lamp or take a measurement). There are around 50 cages within a range of maximum 30 meters that are sometimes lined up or stacked. I was told that the system has to be scalable to control possibly hundreds of cages within 30 meters reach. In the following Image I tried to visualize the rough principle behind:

The communication between the Master and all the slaves do not have to happen at the same time and the measurements on the slave's side are sporadically. Some research showed me that BLE broadcast/advertising could be the way to go. For now I just have to bring up a concept that shows how the system might work. The communication does mainly work from the Master side to the slave side. However, some feedbacks would be great to know that a certain command from the Master side arrived. Since normal microcontrollers do not provide very much signal power, I thought of matching them with a frond-end-module to get 20dBm transmission power. I am not very advanced in wireless communications which is why I wanted to know from you guys where the capabilities/limits are.

What could happen if hundreds of BLE devices are in the same room? Does this have an impact on the communication?
Is a bidirectional communication possible?
Is zigbee/thread maybe the better option? What are the pro's and con's ?

You might ask why I don't want to set up a mesh network: In a Mesh network, the different Slaves do have to transmit information to/from other slaves. Therefore all the Slaves might have to be turned on all the time. With a direct connection, the other slaves could all go back to deep sleep to save power.
What are your overall thoughts on this? Any suggestions?

Surely if your devices can get sent a command at any time they will all need to be listening all the time and won't be able to use deep sleep?

@Finbarr Your point is valid. However, I thought that I will use e.g. 2sec windows where the Slave wakes up for 20ms in every window to scan for advertised/broadcasted information. The Master on the other hand, needs to advertise/broadcast the same information for at least 2seconds to make sure that the slave was listening

Not sure if the details but I have a dozen cheap Amazon Bluetooth sensors in my house logging temperature/humidity and a single receiver ($3 ESP32) in the basement. It has no trouble getting data from the attic through multiple walls. The sensors have been running for a year on the original battery and none report low battery yet so I think this is completely feasible. Especially if in the same room signal is unlikely to be an issue. Maybe take a look at various projects for Bluetooth sensors and see if you can copy something already working?

Your Bluetooth master can send advertising packets to an infinite number of slaves, but depending on the BLE version (4.0 or 5.0 and later etc) the number of simultaneous established comms is limited to 7 for Bluetooth 4.0, but more with 5.1 and higher. Check the modules' manufacturer and the implementation of the stack to get the limits on the maximum number of established continuous comms with slaves.

It seems backwards to me that your "master" device does "broadcast/advertising".  I think each station/cage should have the BLE role of a "peripheral".  And the master/controller should have the BLE role of a "central".  The peripheral stations advertise themselves to the central and respond to connection requests.  The central controller scans for advertising peripherals and requests a connection to the peripheral that it wants to control at that moment...

... Many more peripherals might mean that you have to advertise less frequently to avoid collisions.  Which means that it could take several seconds for the central to discover all the peripherals.  It seems likely that the central will have to connect and configure the peripherals individually and sequentially.  So it may take some time to sequence through and configure or retrieve the status of all the peripherals.
